# link a calendar to another content type

Tags: views

I have a calendar in Drupal 7, and I want to link this calendar with other nodes.

How do I do this? Which module should I use?

I am using Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a "date field" to the test content type.

And with views +date field + calendar you will be able to do it.